# Application Crash on attempt to find record within a hash_map

Tags: c++, string, multithreading, stl, hashmap

I have a multithreaded application that uses a C++ STL `hash_map` to store key-value pairs. The `hash_map` is defined as below:

```
struct eqstr
{
  bool operator()(const string& s1, const string& s2) const
  {
    return (s1 == s2);
  }
};
typedef hash_map<string,UserData, hash<string>, eqstr> DataMap;
DataMap datamap;
```

Where, UserData is a simple structure type having

```
struct UserData
{
    char id[4+1];
    char date[20+1];
    int mode;
};
```

In my application, I have

```
bool found = true;
pthread_mutex_lock(&muCS);
DataMap::iterator itr;
itr = datamap.find(key); // key is a string
if (itr == datamap.end()) 
  found = false;
pthread_mutex_unlock(&muCS);
```

While the application runs, I get a occasional crash, pstack core shows the following:

```
--- called from signal handler with signal 11 (SIGSEGV) ---
 ff31db18 assign__t18string_char_traits1ZcRcRCc (fc07b958, 877f48, 877f58, 2, 1, 662fc0) + 8
 00263f24 c_str__Ct12basic_string3ZcZt18string_char_traits1ZcZt24__default_alloc_template2b0i0 (fc07b958, 83af88, fc07b0c8, 1a, ffbff778, fffc00) + 34
 00346c34 __cl__Ct4hash1Zt12basic_string3ZcZt18string_char_traits1ZcZt24__default_alloc_template2b0i0RCt12basic_string3ZcZt18string_char_traits1ZcZt24__default_alloc_template2b0i0 (77fd59, fc07b958, ffffffff, fc07b0c8, 1a, 80808080) + 18
 00346900 _M_bkt_num_key__Ct9hashtable6Zt4pair2ZCt12basic_string3ZcZt18string_char_traits1ZcZt24__default_alloc_template2b0i0Z8UserDataZt12basic_string3ZcZt18string_char_traits1ZcZt24__default_alloc_template2b0i0Zt4hash1Zt12basic_string3ZcZt18strin (77fd58, fc07b958, c005, fc07b0e2, 1, 1) + 1c
 00346960 _M_bkt_num_key__Ct9hashtable6Zt4pair2ZCt12basic_string3ZcZt18string_char_traits1ZcZt24__default_alloc_template2b0i0Z8UserDataZt12basic_string3ZcZt18string_char_traits1ZcZt24__default_alloc_template2b0i0Zt4hash1Zt12basic_string3ZcZt18strin (77fd58, fc07b958, cc, fc551200, ff2c2030, 10000) + 28
 00347140 find__t9hashtable6Zt4pair2ZCt12basic_string3ZcZt18string_char_traits1ZcZt24__default_alloc_template2b0i0Z8UserDataZt12basic_string3ZcZt18string_char_traits1ZcZt24__default_alloc_template2b0i0Zt4hash1Zt12basic_string3ZcZt18string_char_trai (77fd58, fc07b958, fc551a00, 6633d0, 2922e4, 6633d8) + 18
 003469f0 find__t8hash_map5Zt12basic_string3ZcZt18string_char_traits1ZcZt24__default_alloc_template2b0i0Z8UserDataZt4hash1Zt12basic_string3ZcZt18string_char_traits1ZcZt24__default_alloc_template2b0i0Z5eqstrZt9allocator1Z8UserDataRCt12basic_s (77fd58, fc07b958, fc07b910, 0, 6633d0, 26a0bc) + 1c
```

So, it appears that find within a `hash_map` is failing on STL string.
I have standard guard with semaphore to ensure mutual exclusion.
What could go wrong?
Any remedial suggestion or any workaround would help a lot. Do you feel `hash_map` needs to be changed to some better data structures or any other workaround to prevent crash on stl string?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why hash_map instead of a normal map?

Comment: @Michael to have O(1) during insert using hash, do you feel map would have been better and safer

Comment: well hash_map isn't part of the standard library, I'd at least try unordered_map (C++11 only though)

Comment: Did you debug? Where is it crashing?

Comment: @MariusBancila This happens when data volume being handled is large and pstack of core dumped show the stack trace as shown in the post suspecting on hash_map. so now use std::map instead

Answer (score 1):

I would do the following to fix the crash:

1. Change `hash_map` to either `std::map` if you have no c++11, or to `std::unordered_map`.
2. If you have c++11, use `std::mutex` and `std::unique_lock` instead of `pthread_*` functions. There are two problems with `pthread_mutex_lock` here: they are not exception safe (if some exception would be generated between `pthread_mutex_lock` and `pthread_mutex_unlock`, mutex will never be unlocked, you will get a deadlock), and you do not check this function's return value (if you mutex can not be locked, or is not initialized properly, you'll never know, the error will be silently ignored and you'll get a data race).
3. Check if you use `itr` after `pthread_mutex_unlock` method. Even though the search operation is complete, you can still get a data race cause different threads can try to update the value pointed by the iterator. So this operations should be protected by mutex also.
4. Check that all accesses to your map is protected with one mutex. If you will find out that it is not effective, latter you can always change the lock type (for example to read/write lock) or add one lock per `UserData`.
5. Check your code design. Add your map container to a class and make it private. This way you can control access to it. Add a mutex to this class, and then simply check that mutex is locked once in all the public methods of this class befour the map is accessed.

Please, write back if it help or not.

Comment: Many thanks. Since didn't migrate to C++11 yet, now using std::map getting better results, at least not crashing as before. Not using itr after mutex unlock, also all accesses to map is within class and protected with one mutex, this includes protection for all data access within the map to ensure mutual exclusion.

Comment: @DebasishJana Nice to know that it helped you somehow.